# Linkage error when including npps.h from CUDA 10.0

Tags: c++, linux, cuda, g++

I'm writing a C++ application that will be using CUDA to do some signal processing on the GPU. Since I'm doing signal processing I'm including npps.h which contains the CUDA signal processing functions. However, every time I include npps.h I get linkage errors. I was able to replicate the problem by creating the 1 line file shown below.

CuTest.cpp

```
#include <npps.h>
```

I tried building with the following command:

```
g++ -I/tools/cuda-10.0/include -L/tools/cuda-10.0/lib64  -lnpps -c CuTest.cpp
```

When I try building I get the following errors.

```
In file included from /tools/cuda-10.0/include/cuda_runtime.h:95:0,
                 from /tools/cuda-10.0/include/nppdefs.h:52,
                 from /tools/cuda-10.0/include/npps.h:60,
                 from CuTest.cpp:2:
/tools/cuda-10.0/include/channel_descriptor.h:104:1: error: template with C linkage
 template<class T> __inline__ __host__ cudaChannelFormatDesc cudaCreateChannelDesc(void)
 ^
/tools/cuda-10.0/include/channel_descriptor.h:137:1: error: template specialization with C linkage
 template<> __inline__ __host__ cudaChannelFormatDesc cudaCreateChannelDesc<char>(void)
```

Here is what npps.h looks like:

```
#ifndef NV_NPPS_H
#define NV_NPPS_H

/**
* \file npps.h
* NPP Signal Processing Functionality.
*/

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "nppdefs.h"

/** @defgroup npps NPP Signal Processing
*
* @{
*
*/

#include "npps_support_functions.h"
#include "npps_initialization.h"
#include "npps_conversion_functions.h"
#include "npps_arithmetic_and_logical_operations.h"
#include "npps_statistics_functions.h"
#include "npps_filtering_functions.h"

/** @} end of Signal Processing module */

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif

#endif /* NV_NPPS_H */
```

From the error I got you can see that one of the includes in npps.h that is wrapped in the extern “C” eventually includes a file with template code which is a no-no inside an extern “C”. From the error I got I saw that the offending file was cuda_runtime.h. So, I modified CuTest.cpp to look like the following.

CuTest.cpp:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <npps.h>
```

By including cuda_runtime.h first, because of include guards it will not be included again by npps.h and so when it gets included it will not be wrapped in extern “C”. This worked for CuTest.cpp and doing the same thing in my larger application allowed it to build and run as well.

Here is the configuration I'm running on

```
g++ (GCC) 8.1.0
CUDA 10.0
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

**Note:** I get the same behavior with g++ 4.8.1

Is this a bug in the CUDA headers? Has anybody else seen this or able to reproduce it?

Comment: I can see the issue with cuda 10.1 also.  It appears to be an issue with the CUDA headers.  My suggestion would be to file a bug at developer.nvidia.com.  In the meantime, you already have a workaround which doesn't seem onerous.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks for confirming that you see it too! I will file an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `#include "nppdefs.h"` before `#ifdef __cplusplus` line in the npps.h file:

```
#ifndef NV_NPPS_H
#define NV_NPPS_H

#include "nppdefs.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
...
```